# How to retrieve values from json and store them in an array using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

I am having the JSon file that includes the following items:

```
{
"resource":"A",
"literals":["B","C","D"]
}
```

I would like to retrieve the items B, C and D only and store them in an array as strings. Here is my code:

```
<script>
// Reading the JSon file that has the items above
$.getJSON( "/Users/Docs/sample.json", function( data ) {

$.each( data, function( key, val ) {
    items.push( "<li id='" + key + "'>" + val + "</li>" );
});
</script>
```

Could anyone please help me to get only B, C and D and sore them in an array of strings so I can reuse them for later in another script? Your help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: `data.literals` will be your array of strings.

Comment: The items `B`, `C` and `D` are already stored as strings in an array, just use `data.literals` to get them

Comment: You replied with a piece of codes. I copied it and pasted. It is working correctly. Please add your codes that you have removed. That was what I needed. Thank you very much.

Comment: @user2864315 fair enough, if it helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I've misunderstood the question, you need to access the array in the object by `data.literals`. Try this:

```
$.getJSON("/Users/Docs/sample.json", function(data) {    
    $.each(data.literals, function(i, val) {
        items.push("<li id='" + val + "'>" + val + "</li>" );
    });
});
```